# What "wrong crowd" is he referring to?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), after locking River, Malcolm had a talk with his members:

> Jayne: She goes woolly again, we're gonna have to put a bullet to her.
>
> Malcolm: It's crossed my mind.
>
> Hoban: Can I make a suggestion that doesn't involve violence, or is
> this the **wrong crowd**?

What "wrong crowd" is he referring to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wash is simply asking if his comrades are dead set on the idea of resolving their problems with gunplay, or whether they're open to a more benign idea, in this case going to see their friend Mr Universe to determine what damage has been caused by River's display in the bar.

In this instance, the line should probably read "wrong ***audience***" (e.g. the incorrect group of people to be 'selling' something to), but these are a group of desperados we're dealing with, so they're also [the wrong crowd](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrong_crowd) (e.g. people who are a bad influence generally)

---

The line could be rewritten:
"*Can I please make a suggestion that doesn't involve violence, **or is this the wrong group of people to be trying to suggest that to, because you seem very keen on using violence to resolve this situation.***"]

Comment: I think "wrong crowd" is commonly used as a synonym for "wrong audience", for example I googled "talking to the wrong crowd" and the first thing that came up was a [quote](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/863492) from Geordi LaForge trying to hype a new technology to an unenthusiastic audience